# How to format the current date and time into a stream of characters?

Tags: .net, string, date, time, format

What is the easiest way to create a string of characters that is the following formatting of the current date and time?

```
YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

eg. `20131003163215`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.ToString(fmt)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) with a [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
var t = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"); // with milliseconds
var u = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff"); // with microseconds
```

Or use a DateTime variable instead of `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Sure. I modified my answer for one line. Of course you can also use a DateTime variable if necessary.

Comment: How can I get milliseconds as well?

Comment: @CJ7 fractional seconds are specified with the 'f' format. You can use up to 7 'f' specifiers (sec^-7). See the custom format link for more information.